# Why is it jsf unable to call validate method using jsf validator attribute in property type of Integer instead another error message appears?

Tags: hibernate, jsf-2, richfaces, seam

I want to validate a simple field which must contain numbers only.The value property is bounded to an instance of seam entity Home.

The code

```
<h:inputText id="text" value="#{personHome.intance.age}" 
    validator="#{bean.validateAge}">
   <a4j:support event="onblur" reRender="text, errorAge" />
</h:inputText>
<rich:message id="errorAge" for="text" styleClass="errors"/>
```

The instance of PersonHome is mapped correctly using hibernate annotation.

The problem is another error message appears and the method validateAge() is not called. Hence i cannot override the message properly and add my own custome validation rules.

The error message that appear is:

```
value must be an integer number between -2147483648 and 2147483647
```

Is it the hibernate validator?
Can somebody tell me what i am missing here.

Answer (score 2):

You might have a seam

```
<s:validateAll>
```

or

```
<s:validate>
```

tag around your input text(s). They trigger the hibernate validators on the bean fields. You can either remove the

```
<s:validate>
```

tag in which case your validate method will be called, or you can create your custom hibernate validator (@Age) to put it on your age bean field and remove the validator attribute from the input text.

UPDATE:

There is also a third option: to create a custom jsf validator (not validator method), register it with seam and apply it to the input text.

```
@BypassInterceptors
@Name("yourAgeValidator")
@org.jboss.seam.annotations.faces.Validator
public class YourAgeValidator

@Override
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    ....
}


<h:inputText id="text" value="#{personHome.intance.age}"  validator="yourAgeValidator">
```

Comment: i will try this one. i will inform you if its work for me..thanks for the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted anything about validateAge method does it adhere to

```
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent toValidate, Object value)
```

signature.

Comment: yes indeed. Ive tried on the other input text which value is String in the model it works perfectly. But when use on the value which are bounded to Integer property in the model the message appears.